# Community toolkit Popup - Close from ViewModel

Tags: maui

I am looking for a way to close popup from viewmodel or service created to show or close popup. Popup close event code is handled at code behind of popup page. we have old xamarin application which are migrating to .net maui in that we have used popup plugin for popup, but currently we want to less reliant on any other plugins for popup. Earlier the plugins used interface to expose open and close event for popup. In toolkit popup
I don't found any such interface or way to do so.

I tried using code behind function but there is no way I am able to trigger that event from service used

Comment: Hi Kiran welcome to SO, unfortunately you might need to check out this guide on how to ask a good question [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](SO guide) as you might not get any results with out posting a minimal example of what code you have tried to date.

Comment: Use [Community Toolkit Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) to have the view model communicate with the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well while creating an activity indicator popup, as far as I know the only way to get this to work is to publish an event to which your popup code behind is subscribed to and closed itself. I ended up creating a service to make opening and closing the activity popup easier:

```
public class ActivityIndicatorService : IActivityIndicatorService
{
private readonly IPopupService _popupService;

public ActivityIndicatorService(IPopupService popupService)
{
    _popupService = popupService;
}

public void Close()
{
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, Events.CloseActivityPopup);
}

public async Task Open()
{
    _popupService.ShowPopupAsync<ActivityIndicatorPopupViewModel>();
}
}
```

and in the code behind:

```
public partial class ActivityIndicatorPopup : Popup
{
public ActivityIndicatorPopup(ActivityIndicatorPopupViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm;
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ActivityIndicatorService>(this, Events.CloseActivityPopup, async (_) => await CloseEventHandler());
}

private async Task CloseEventHandler()
{
    await CloseAsync();
}
}
```